# How do i use case statement to

Tags: java, javascript, html

Example, if input `print hi there` how would I go about removing `print` and just outputting `hi there` using case statements ?

I've been stuck thinking on how to do this for days and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: "print hi there".substr(6)

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh is referring to the fact that you provided no criteria for splitting "print" from "hi there". You gave us a single example, and his solution will work for it.

Comment: I think if we saw your current attempt we would be better able to help you

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages.  Which are you actually using?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear but if you want to use the first word as a sort of 'command', I guess you could extract the first word and use switch on it. 
Assuming your input is in a String called input:

```
String firstWord = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(' '));
switch(firstWord) {
     case "print" : System.out.println(input.substring(input.indexOf(' ') + 1));
                    break;
     ....
}
```

Comment: Judging from the OP's other question, it looks like they actually meant JavaScript, not Java at all. :|

Comment: Just a sidenote: `case` with `Strings` only works if its `JDK-7` or higher.